# Using linq to group/aggregate by string[]

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a list with a Tuple.First as a string[] (i.e. my key):

```
var lst = new List<Tuple<string[], int>> {
     new Tuple<string[], int>(new string[] { "A", "B" }, 5),
     new Tuple<string[], int>(new string[] { "A", "B" }, 10),
     new Tuple<string[], int>(new string[] { "C", "B" }, 10),
}
```

I would like to aggregate (e.g. Sum) by Tuple.First (i.e. string[]) so expecting an output as follows:

```
var output = new List<Tuple<string[], int>> {
     new Tuple<string[], int>(new string[] { "A", "B" }, 15),
     new Tuple<string[], int>(new string[] { "C", "B" }, 10),
}
```

I did it this way but there must be a cleaner way to do it instead of forcing a pipe concatenation:

```
var output = lst
    .GroupBy(x => string.Join("|", x.First))
    .Select(x => new Tuple<string[], int>( 
             x.Key.Split('|'),   
             Sum(x => x.Second)));
```

Comment: why object (array) is a key?

Comment: I want to group by string[]

Comment: Where does the `Pair` class come from? How do you access the values that you pass to its constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `IEqualityComparer` for `string[]`. My example using touples (You don't say what `Pair` is):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lst = new List<(string[] arr, int num)> {
        (new string[] { "A", "B" }, 5),
        (new string[] { "A", "B" }, 10),
        (new string[] { "C", "B" }, 10),
    };

    var grouped = lst.GroupBy(pair => pair.arr, new EnumerableComparer());
    var sums = grouped.Select(g => (arr: g.Key, num: g.Sum(p => p.num)));
}

class EnumerableComparer<TRecord> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<TRecord>>
    {
        public bool Equals(IEnumerable<TRecord> x, IEnumerable<TRecord> y)
        {
            return ReferenceEquals(x, y) || x != null && x.SequenceEqual(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<TRecord> lst)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 387;
                foreach (var elem in lst)
                {
                    hash = hash * 31 + elem.GetHashCode();
                }

                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Denis what was wrong with using native `HashCode` class?

Comment: It wouldn't resolve with R#. Maybe it needs a high version of .Net?